# prettier - disable auto closing of html tags

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

How to disable/avoid prettier to auto-close an HTML tag on formating?
I tried `"html.autoClosingTags": false` in vs code settings.json, but It does not work.

**Before formatting:**

```
<body>
    <h1>home page</h1>
```

**After formatting:**

```
<body>
    <h1>home page</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your JSX the code you need:

```
{
  "javascript.autoClosingTags": false,
  "typescript.autoClosingTags": false
}
```

In order for your tags not to automatically close. You can also adjust this in your preferences per version # 16.11.

> Go to File > Preferences > Settings, search for html. autoClosingTags and set it to false . This will make it so when you type  , it won't insert  automatically, but if you start typing </ , it won't close the tag automatically.